# How to make table split in two pages

Tags: tables, longtable, elsarticle

I am writing a paper using the `elsarticle` document class. However, the article contains a long table which is sent to the next page, in the middle of the page although I have specified the position as 'here'. Is there any way to make the table split if one page is not long enough for the table?

Thank you very much for your very kind help.

Comment: The [longtable](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools) package and its eponymous environment should help you get the job done.

Comment: I found it quite difficult to make sense of longtable for me as a latex beginner. I am looking for a way to do it without the longtable package. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You also have the `ltablex` package, which combines the functionalities of `longtable` and `tabularx`.

Comment: the use of longtable is essentially identical to that of tabular, if you get an error you could ask a question about that, but `table` will never break and neither will `tabular` do you need to not use either of those environments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To switch from a `table`/`tabular` combination to a `longtable` setup, the following adjustments are required:

- delete `\begin{tabular}{ccc}` and change `\begin{table}` to `\begin{longtable}{ccc}`;
- delete `\end{tabular}` and change `\end{table}` to `\end{longtable}`;
- terminate the `\caption` directive with a double backslash;
- omit the `\centering` directive that's usually provided for `tabular` material; and
- organize the header and footer material with `\endhead`, `\endfoot` and, if needed, `\endfirsthead` and `\endlastfoot`, directives.

In the following screenshot, the tabular-like material and the positions of the captions look exactly the same for both tables; the first group was generated with a `table`/`tabular` combination, whereas the second was generated with a `longtable` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{With \texttt{table} and \texttt{tabular} environments}\label{tab:a}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
H1 & H2 & H3 \\
\hline
123 & 456 & 789 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}

% header and footer information
\caption{With \texttt{longtable} environment}\label{tab:b}\\
\hline
H1 & H2 & H3 \\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\endfoot

% body of table
123 & 456 & 789 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```