# Change table to longtable to span multiple pages

Tags: tables, longtable, page-breaking

I have a table with 4 columns like this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
 \begin{tabular}{l l l l}
    \caption{Test} 
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{l l l l}
            Column Name 1 & \ Column Name 2 & Column Name 3 & Column Name 4 \\
            v1 & \ v1 & v1 & v1 \\
 \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Now, I want my table to span multiple pages since there are a lot of rows. I have read that I could use the `longtable` function for this as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages). However, simply exchanging `table` with `longtable` (as I had hoped) does not work.

Is there a convenient way to achieve this without changing the code too much?

Thanks!

Comment: The syntax should be `\begin{longtable}{l l l l} \caption{Test} \\ Column Name 1 & …`. In other words, you exchange table with longtable, and remove the `tabular` environment. You also can add a table head   at each new page.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301249/134144 contains an easy to follow step-by-step recipe that might help you to switch from `table`+`tabular` to `longtable`.